need extension for debug
i found Visual Studio Code and installed Pascal 9.8
but there he wants a configuration launch.json.
the default and the example from the web-help do not work.
the message is need extension for debug, but
freepas and gdb and VMS are making no app.
i tried
source Begin Write("Hello");End.
installed pascal 9.8 , 3 marketplace extensions.
target is an exe of my pascal-source.

I found that searching the internet for set up pascal language in Visual Studio Code very informative.
